# quotient space of similar matrices is not Hausdorff?

Tags: quotient-spaces, separation-axioms, similar-matrices

This is a problem of my midterm test...

Denote invertible $2\times 2$ matrices on $\mathbb{C}$ by ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, and define the conjugation action of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ on itself by what it usually means $(A,B)\mapsto ABA^{-1}$, then we get the orbit space of this action equipped with quotient topology. The problem is to prove that this space is not Hausdorff.

I heard that for any 2 dissimilar matrices $A,B$, we can always find a matrix similar to $A$ in any, arbitrarily small neighborhood of $B$.

Is that true? If is, how does it help with the proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to show that $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & z\\
 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & w\\
 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ are similar whenever $z,w\neq 0$, and then  ask yourself whether these matrices are similar to the identity matrix.